# Disable physical forward/back-buttons i ChromeOS kiosk app

Tags: kiosk, kiosk-mode, google-chrome-os, chromebook

We're using Chromebooks in Kiosk-mode and I'm wondering if it is possible to disable the physical buttons for back/forward?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? Because i'm having the same problem now?